# How can I generate random number of operands and operators for a paricular expression?

Tags: php, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBl8t.png)

```
if(isset($_POST['digits']) == 1){  //here 1 is for single digit operands 
 only
$rand1 = rand(0, 9);
$rand2 = rand(0,9);
$operator = array('+', '-','*','/');
$randoperator = $operator[rand(0,3)];
switch ($randoperator) {
case "+":
    $finaalvalue1 = $rand1 + $rand2;
    break;
case "-":
    $finaalvalue1 = $rand1 - $rand2;
    break;
 case "*":
    $finaalvalue1 = $rand1 * $rand2;
    break;
 case "/":
    $finaalvalue1 = $rand1 / $rand2;
    break;

}
echo ("This is Q(".$x."):"), $rand1 . $randoperator . $rand2 . '=' . 
$finaalvalue1 ,'<br /><br />'; 
}
```

the above code is working properly but for only two  opearands (rand1 & rand2), if user gave any input through form
which I have created (suppose user gave input of 50 operands) then what should I do to generate them randomly ?

This is the form I am trying to submit

```
<form action="" method="POST">
 Select no.of questions:<input type="number" name="que" value="que"><br>
 <br>
 Select no. of series: <input type="number" name="ser" value="ser">
  <br><br>
  Select number type(in digits) <input type="number" name="digits" 
 value="digits">
  <br><br>
  Select operations:<br />
 <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation" value="addition" 
 id="check1"><label>Addition</label><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="operation" value="substraction" 
id="check2"><label>substraction</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation" value="multiplication" 
id="check3"><label>Multiplication</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation" value="division" 
id="check4"><label>Division</label><br/>
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate"><br>
 <br>


 </form>
```

This is  the screenshot of output for the above code 
In this image The only field is not working properly is "no. of series " field.
If you observe the output you can se there are 2 questions and also answers of that resp questions.Now, "this is output showing only for the expressioon which has 2 operands i.e(here no.of operands in a series(or say expression) showing is 2 )" and As you can see in input field I have given input for 3, but it still showing output for 2, 
So How can I fix it if user gives input for ex. "no. of series = 50".
   there should be an output which will show  50 operands and 49 operators in a series(or say in an expression)?

Comment: please share the form that you are trying to submit.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to achieve? A little bit more explanation and a little bit more code, like the form submited would help. Right now `$_POST[digits]` is a single submitted and checked variable, and it's not clear how it relates to the user's input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please check now.!

Comment: @user10625430 It's not clear what are you trying to reach there. Please write a full scenario example including the expected Input, Implementation, and the Output.

Answer (score 1):

If you need many random operands, you should create them in a loop and store them to an array:

```
// initialize array
$randomOperands = array();

// do a loop over $i fifty times:
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i ++) {
        // assign random operand to array slot
        $randomOperands[] = rand(0, 9);
}

// print array values:
print_r($randomOperands);
```

You can learn everything you need to know about arrays here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Have fun learning php!

Comment: Thank you its working but the I want output in a format as shown in screenshot  so , what should i do to generate that output ?

Comment: hey can you tell me how can I validate those numeric fields in my form ?